# Qual è una traduzione di "OP"?

Tags: word-choice, translation, phrase-request

Nella parte di internet in lingua inglese (incluso questo stesso sito!) si usa spesso il termine "Original Poster" o "OP" in breve per indicare la persona che ha iniziato una discussione (o, nel caso di StackExchange, che ha posto la domanda).

Ho pensato per un po' ma non riesco ad immaginare un termine analogo in italiano (principalmente per la mancanza di un verbo "postare", "postatore" suona semplicemente orribile).

> **Q:** Qual è una traduzione in italiano di "Original Poster", come usato su internet?

Comment: A meno che non emerga che in qualche specifica comunità c'è una traduzione attestata, mi suona un po' opinion-based...

Comment: @DaG Mah adesso non esageriamo. Chiedere come tradurre un'espressione è considerato perfettamente accettabile in praticamente tutti is siti SE sulle lingue, e non è poi così arbitrario. Andrebbe meglio se rimpiazzassi "buona traduzione" con "traduzione possibile"?

Comment: "Autore Originale"? Anche se vedrei bene "Primo Oratore" :-)

Comment: Capisco bene, e non credere che non sia un tipo di questione molto caro anche a me. Ma, a parte che le traduzioni sono sempre, già di per sé, un tasto delicato su SE, potrebbe quasi sembrare che tu chieda di creare un modo di rendere questo concetto. Vediamo che cosa viene fuori.

Comment: @LSerni *Primo Oratore*! Sono tentato di cominciare ad usarlo, anche se non so quanti coglierebbero il riferimento :) Che ne dici di convertire il tuo commento in una risposta?

Comment: Voterei per "autore originale"

Comment: Vogliamo tutti bene ad Asimov, ma cose come “Primo Oratore” sono proprio le risposte opinion-based che temevo. I siti SE prevedono domande e risposte su fatti preesistenti, attestati, riferibili a fonti, non idee originali create per l'occasione, per quanto azzeccate. Altrimenti ci avviciniamo a quello che chiedeva come chiamare il gatto (o non so che animale fosse).

Comment: @DaG Immagino fosse una battuta, non un suggerimento serio :) Almeno la mia esortazione a scrivere una risposta si riferiva ad "autore originale". Ad ogni modo, se hai obiezioni a questo tipo di domande, che ne dici di scrivere un post su meta? I commenti non sono davvero un buon posto per queste discussioni

Comment: @LSerni Se hai tempo, ho messo una bounty per una settimana e penso che una tua risposta vincerebbe facilmente i punti :).

Comment: Dato che ci tieni metto la risposta, ma un Bounty mi sembra eccessivo :-). Riserviamolo a un'altra occasione, tanto non mancherà.

Comment: Adesso abbiamo la [domanda sul Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1366/707).

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @DaG che la domanda così formulata sembra una richiesta di proposte per traduzione, che va contro il modello di questo sito.

Comment: @egreg:  Non sarebbe lo stesso per questa [domanda su ELU.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473261/short-blurb-style-wording-for-pizza-made-at-the-establishment)? Non si tratta anche di una richiesta di proposte di espressioni per esprimere un certo concetto (o di traduzioni dal polacco)?

Comment: @Charo: Ho risposto alla tua osservazione in un commento su Meta. In breve: la differenza è che in quella domanda su ELU si chiedono e si ottengono traduzioni attestate (sul _New York Times_, su testi di cucina, su raccolte di frasi idiomatiche), non espressioni proposte da chi rispondeva.

Comment: In Italiano comunque, nell'ambito dei social media e di internet, l'utilizzo di acronimi inglesi è una pratica comune (probabilmente il più diffuso è _LOL_) quindi, al di là di un "vezzo personale", per così dire, personalmente non trovo ci sia una forte motivazione per cercare una traduzione di _OP_.

Answer (score 9):

Alla lettera direi "autore originale". Da una ricerca su Google, questo è anche l'uso diffuso, anche se non sono riuscito a trovare una fonte abbastanza autorevole, e non so se [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisorsupport.com/hc/it/articles/200613597-Il-linguaggio-dei-forum) o [Plreply](https://preply.com/it/blog/2018/05/04/le-abbreviazioni-piu-usate-su-internet-nei-messaggi-e-nei-tweet/) meritino la tramoggia.

Su Usenet ho visto usare "capothread" in senso metonimico, per indicare non solo il primo post ma anche il suo autore (non è una traduzione e anzi è proprio brutto, visto che mezzo termine resta inglese).

(E poi si potrebbe usare "Primo Oratore").

Comment: A volte ho visto "thread" tradotto come "filone". Quindi, invece di "capothread", si potrebbe dire "capofilone".

Comment: +1 Non so se sia veramente un uso “diffuso”, ma apprezzo la ricerca. Certo, TripAdvisor etc. non sono autorità linguistiche, ma queste pagine ci dicono che la locuzione “autore originale” nel senso di OP esiste veramente “in natura”, per così dire.

Comment: Oratore per qualcuno che posta su un sito non mi convince proprio

Answer (score 2):

Nel caso di Stack Exchange, in cui il primo post è una domanda, si potrebbe anche usare [querente](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/querente/), parola un po démodé che secondo me alcuni utenti apprezzeranno.

Volendo anche [petente](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/petente/), ma forse suona un po' male. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Io propongo “richiedente originale” o “primo richiedente”.

Si potrebbe anche ipotizzare “iniziatore originale” ma a mio parere stona un pochino.

Comment: Mi sembra meglio di "autore originale", almeno in quei casi, che poi sono la maggioranza, in cui si parla di richieste (Stack Overflow et al.).

Answer (score 1):

A mio avviso, si possono proporre diverse traduzioni, più o meno creative, più o meno letterali ma si sta perdendo di vista il contesto dell'utilizzo del termine.

Come qualsiasi altro acronimo diffuso in internet, OP viene utilizzato perché

1. è più breve dell'espressione che sostituisce e
2. perché il suo significato è noto.

Qualsiasi traduzione di "*original poster*" mancherebbe degli stessi requisiti poiché sarebbe sempre e comunque più lunga di OP e, "convertita" in un acronimo, sarebbe incomprensibile a tutti.

Quindi, all'atto pratico, IMHO (e non "AMMA" o "AMMP" ;-) ), la risposta alla domanda "*Qual è una traduzione in italiano di "Original Poster", come usato su internet?*" è "Non ha senso tradurlo".